# Migration of Documents with quick-parts

Tags: document-library, word, quick-parts

I am currently migrating a few thousands Documents from one Sharepoint to another, which has worked fine.

Sadly the quick-parts inside those Documents are no longer syncing. The quickparts refer to some columns in the document libraries. If a change one of those parameters in the new library, they won't change inside the document. Removing and adding every quick part fixes the issue, but doing this for all documents would be an incredible amount of work.

I found a few solutions, for example https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/fix-for-quickparts-not-working-after-sharepoint-onpremise-to-o365-migration and https://www.rlvision.com/blog/hacking-docx-files-to-fix-quick-parts-in-word-online/. But I was not able to adjust those scripts for my purposes. So I was wondering if someone has found a solution to this known problem. Many thanks for your help <3